# Yajra DataTable addColumn

Tags: laravel-5, yajra-datatable

I use yajra datatable but i've get problem when I use the method "addColumn".
the one I use that method is work properly, but the other doesn't

this is my source code :

```
        ->addColumn('action', function($arrProduct){
          return
              '<center><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  href="'.route('packaging.edit',['id' => $arrProduct['id'], 'product_id'=> $arrProduct['product_id']]).'">
                  <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>&nbsp;Proses</a></center>';
        })
        ->addColumn('status', function($arrProduct){
            if($arrProduct['status_produksi']){
              return ucwords($arrProduct['status_produksi']);
            }else{
              $tag = "<center><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>
                  <i class='fa fa-refresh'></i>Belum Diproses</a></center>";
              return $tag;
            }
        })
        ->make(true);
```

and this is the problem :
[image]

one of them (column action) is work properly, but why in the other (column status) the "addColumn" doesn't work?

pls somebody help me.. thank's anyway

Comment: Instead of sending using double quotes, use single quotes. Like you used for previous column "Process".

Comment: these are 2 different column.. how could I use single "addColumn" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `->rawColumns(['status', 'action'])`

before `->make(true);`